# Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rt

Tags: android

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rt
   at rs.(SourceFile:17)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onSaveInstanceState(SourceFile:201)
   at android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:13651)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchFreezeSelfOnly(ViewGroup.java:2835)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchSaveInstanceState(SourceFile:220)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2821)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2821)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2821)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2821)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2821)
   at android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:13634)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentViewState(FragmentManager.java:2594)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:2615)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:2678)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.saveAllState(FragmentController.java:134)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:571)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onSaveInstanceState(AppCompatActivity.java:509)
   at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1229)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1229)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3390)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:169)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: paste your code where error occurs

Comment: does you app working in marshmallow or upper versions

Comment: I don't know where it's occurred.Just get this crash log in Fabric crashlytics.

Comment: we're experiencing the same crash :(

Comment: Same crash if the page is closed. :(

Comment: Even I am facing this issue. For me this crash occurs when I play a video with youtubePlayerFragment and minimize. This issue has come up with youtube update.

Comment: We also experiencing this crash.

Comment: Check out simple hack at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44571262/noclassdeffounderror-crash-on-minimizing-youtube-player-on-android-4-0-4-2-4-4

Comment: @UmeshIsran We are having the same issue. No crash is reported with the Youtube App removed.

Comment: @TerenceLui Thats true. Only the latest update of youtube has bought in this issue. There may a better solution to avoid this crash, but for now I am using the hack from my post.

Comment: Same here, seems to occur when the app tries to perform a saveState and from my crash reports only happens on API 19

Answer (score 8):

I fix this by release YouTubePlayer at onSavedInstanceState and onStop.

```
@Nullable
protected YouTubePlayer mUtPlayer;

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    /* release ut when home button pressed. */
    if (mUtPlayer != null) {
        mUtPlayer.release();
    }
    mUtPlayer = null;
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    /* release ut when go to other fragment or back pressed */
    if (mUtPlayer != null) {
        mUtPlayer.release();
    }
    mUtPlayer = null;
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: I added another answer, but it's basically the same logic

Answer (score 3):

For the people that the solution of Razgriz does not work, just add the same lines in `onPause` instead of in `onSaveInstanceState` and `onStop`, and initialize the `YouTubePlayerFragment` in `onResume` instead of in `onCreate` so it'll be available every time the activity is in foreground and released when the app goes to the background:

**Note that the code should always be placed after the `super` methods.**

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment =
                (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeFragmentView);
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(YouTubeDeveloperKey, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (youTubePlayer != null) {
            youTubePlayer.release();
        }
        youTubePlayer = null;
    }
```

Comment: This fix causes the player to throw internal error each time the application comes back from `onPause()` on all devices (where I wasn't even getting this issue). So does the solution from @Razgriz Bill Wong.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case the given solution above didn't work for you, consider the next one, it works! The trick here is to avoid saving the state of all views related to YouTube. Surely the solution has its drawbacks, but it is better than the app crashing like happened with mine:

```
public interface ICallableOnView {
    void call(View view);
}

public static void recursiveCallOnView(View view, ICallableOnView callableOnView) {
    if (view != null) {
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                recursiveCallOnView(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i), callableOnView);
            }
        }
        callableOnView.call(view);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Disable view state saving to prevent saving states from youtube apk which cannot be restored.
    // This is to avoid the bug "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rt at rs.<clinit>(SourceFile:17)"
    recursiveCallOnView(mViewHolder.youTubeVideoContainerLayout, new ICallableOnView() {
        @Override
        public void call(View view) {
            view.setSaveEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Hope this helps somebody, blessings to all.