# activity crash with YouTubePlayerView when app is minimize

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have integrated YouTubePlayerView library into our app and its working perfectly but whenever I minimize the app it crashes or you can say whenever the app goes in the background it crashes.

Here is the crash log:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rt
        at rs.<clinit>(SourceFile:17)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onSaveInstanceState(SourceFile:201)
        at android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:12985)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchFreezeSelfOnly(ViewGroup.java:2643)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchSaveInstanceState(SourceFile:220)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2629)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2629)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2629)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2629)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2629)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2629)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2629)
        at android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:12968)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.saveHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1705)
        at android.app.Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1277)
        at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity.onSaveInstanceState(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1226)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3342)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3401)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1320)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-03 13:02:44.608 31106-31174/com.seeken D/FA: Logging event (FE): _ae, Bundle[{_o=crash, timestamp=1499067164609, fatal=1}]
07-03 13:02:44.808 31106-31106/com.seeken I/dalvikvm: Could not find method java.util.Locale.toLanguageTag, referenced from method bme.a
07-03 13:02:44.808 31106-31106/com.seeken W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 10275: Ljava/util/Locale;.toLanguageTag ()Ljava/lang/String;
07-03 13:02:44.808 31106-31106/com.seeken D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00e4
07-03 13:02:44.848 31106-31106/com.seeken D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3454K, 15% free 20646K/24152K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
07-03 13:02:44.868 31106-31106/com.seeken E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.seeken, PID: 31106
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rt
    at rs.<clinit>(SourceFile:17)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onSaveInstanceState(SourceFile:201)
    at android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:12985)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchFreezeSelfOnly(ViewGroup.java:2643)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchSaveInstanceState(SourceFile:220)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2629)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2629)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2629)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2629)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2629)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2629)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2629)
    at android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:12968)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.saveHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1705)
    at android.app.Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1277)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity.onSaveInstanceState(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1226)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3342)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3401)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:139)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1320)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.VideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may refer with this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558166/fatal-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-rt) that suggested some workaround which might help:

- Release `YouTubePlayer` at `onSavedInstanceState` and `onStop`.

> ```
> @Nullable
> protected YouTubePlayer mUtPlayer;
>
> @Override
> public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
>     /* release ut when home button pressed. */
>     if (mUtPlayer != null) {
>         mUtPlayer.release();
>     }
>     mUtPlayer = null;
>     super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onStop() {
>     /* release ut when go to other fragment or back pressed */
>     if (mUtPlayer != null) {
>         mUtPlayer.release();
>     }
>     mUtPlayer = null;
>     super.onStop();
> }
> ```

- If it doesn't work, just add the same lines in `onPause` instead of in `onSaveInstanceState` and `onStop`, and initialize the `YouTubePlayerFragment` in `onResume` instead of in `onCreate` so it'll be available every time the activity is in foreground and released when the app goes to the background.

Additional reference:

- [NoClassDefFoundError Crash on Minimizing Youtube Player on Android 4.0, 4.2, 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44571262/noclassdeffounderror-crash-on-minimizing-youtube-player-on-android-4-0-4-2-4-4)

Answer (score 0):

i think your application is crashing when restarting because of a configuration changes

You can disable the automatic activity recreation for orientation changes, and handle it yourself.

To do that, add

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"
```

for more information [runtime-changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

or add this code in your activity

```
@Nullable
protected YouTubePlayer mUtPlayer;

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
/* release ut when home button pressed. */
if (mUtPlayer != null) {
    mUtPlayer.release();
}
mUtPlayer = null;
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
/* release ut when go to other fragment or back pressed */
if (mUtPlayer != null) {
    mUtPlayer.release();
}
mUtPlayer = null;
super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: I have already added `android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"` this code in manifest but still facing issue. Please check.